# How to send user data from one website to another

Tags: ssl, https, curl

I need to send user data (some parts of `user` and `user_meta`), from Website A to Website B (both are Wordpress Websites) over a secure Protocol, after clicking on a button. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160545/best-secure-data-transmission-method), a secure method would be the ssl protocol (https).

Or in other words, **I need the user data of Website A also on Website B** (different Server). I have full access to both sites.

What are the **best practice** and are there already some tools to do that? Where to find good documentation for this task?

In my research I could find only Client to Server communication like here: [developer.mozilla.org/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

But I'm looking actually for ways to send data to another website (on another server). I guess my case is **server-to-server** communication?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are these WordPress sites?

Comment: why the downvote?! Yes both are wordpress websites. Because of that I've  posted my question here!

Comment: The downvote isn't from me. :) The reason is given in the tool tip on the down arrow: "no research efforts".

Comment: There's not enough information here to give a precise answer, by user data, are you talking about the entire user and user meta table? Roles? Is this a continuous synchronisation or a one off copying? Or are you referring to a users posts? Or particular parts of a users data? Some users but not other? Please be clearer what you mean by 'user data' so that an appropriate answer can be written, and please indicate what you've tried so far

Comment: Also keep in mind you're walking towards legal and regulatory issues concerning privacy and data protection

Comment: @TomJNowell: Thanks for your answer. I edited my post, according to your concerns. Also I know about the Privacy act. It have to be a secure way without data loss and the user has to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a possible solution for my question.

The technology I was looking for is `curl`. Look at this posts for more Informations:

- [stackoverflow.com/transfer-php-variables-from-one-server-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618484/transfer-php-variables-from-one-server-to-another)
- [stackoverflow.com/sending-data-across-websites-using-from-http-and-receiving-in-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017996/sending-data-across-websites-using-from-http-and-receiving-in-https)

Also I this Blog Article quite useful:https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post-file